# To find out if a div has a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

If a div is set as `overflow:auto`, how can I find out (using plain JS) if a scrollbar (Vertical / Horizontal) has been rendered?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Check if [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientHeight) is smaller than [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight).

Comment: Finding every element on page that has a scrollbar `[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(x => x.clientHeight < x.scrollHeight)`

Comment: I tried this...
`function isOverflown(element)
{
 return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
}

function scroll_notification()
{
 if(isOverflown(document.getElementById("myDiv")))
 {
  // function content
 }
}`

but I get this error... ***TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'element.scrollHeight')***