# CSS Style applied only on scrollable elements

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` element with a fixed height and `overflow:auto`.
I want to  apply a style only when the content is large enough for it to scroll. Example: I want to apply a inset box shadow to the bottom of the box when it is scrollable, but when the content is not large enough I don't want the box shadow to be visible.

...Preferably not using script and as cross-browser as possible.

**UPDATE**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rr6t/) as requested

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with pure css. Perhaps its possible with something like LESS, but that's a script indirectly. This is easily achievable with jQuery.

Comment: maybe you show us your markup with your div and or create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar thanks, I might just do it with jquery then if no-one comes up with a different answer.

Comment: @caramba: Fiddle added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unfortunately...you cant (using only CSS/HTML)

(sorry)

**However**, and I know you specified you don't want to use a script, but it is relatively straightforward, e.g. using jQuery:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p3FFL/984/)

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.toggleScrollClass = function () {
    this.each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('hasScroll', this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight);
    });
}
$('div').toggleScrollClass();
```

CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.hasScroll {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: However you can find numerous examples on stackoverflow.com that use script to detect scroll, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880381/check-whether-html-element-has-scrollbars , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible , and not limited to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768667/to-find-out-if-a-div-has-a-scrollbar

Comment: Thanks. I guess this should be the accepted answer since it's the best alternative.

Comment: Does this work on multiple elements at the same time? As in `$('.funkybox').toggleScrollClass();` it seems that it is changing all the elements based on the scrollable value of the first element.

Comment: @hofnarwillie - easily fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p3FFL/984/

Comment: Thanks! Please tell me what the `interval` parameter is for?

Comment: @hofnarwillie - nothing, I've removed